# How to redirect from email to a frontend page in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, sendgrid

I am writing a script for confirmation email in nodejs and vuejs. So, when user signs up a verification email has been sent to the user's email address. now when the user clicks "verify your email" button in the email, it has to redirect to a frontend page view.

> **Problem:** Redirect does not work

In the verify button I have put the link in the following way:

```
const confirmTokenUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/api/confirm-email/confirm-token/${confirmToken}`

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_KEY)

const mail = {
    to: req.user.email,
    from: {
      email: process.env.SG_SENDER,
      name: "xyz",
    },
    subject: "Email Confirmation",
    html: `
    <h1>Hello ${req.user.username}!</h1>
    <a style="
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 15px 30px;
        background-color: #13f195;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
        "
      href="${confirmTokenUrl}"
      target="_blank"
    >
     Confirm your email
    </a>
    `
}

await sgMail.send(mail)

res.status(200).json({
    success: true
})
```

now for making verification work, I have written another endpoint. I am expecting this endpoint to be fired when the user clicks the verify button in that email. In the controller of that endpoint I have given redirect notation to response object like the following:

```
res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login"); //frontend page
```

now the problem is it doesn't redirect to the frontend page. Now could you explain what I am missing ?

Comment: Can you add where `res.redirect` is being called?

Comment: I have edited in the bottom of the question. it's being called from BE verify endpoint controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with "no-cache" header, otherwise browser will be caching url and redirecting to frontend without making get request to confirm email

```
 res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max- stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 res.writeHead(301,{Location:process.env.CLIENT_URL + /login} )
 res.end()
```